# Defining new shortcuts in TexStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio

1. This is not about new macros like `\newcommand`, `\def` and others.
2. This is not about autocompletion like using `.cwl` (in TexStudio)
3. This is **also not** about using shortcuts for predefined commands that are listed in the shortcuts sections.

It is more closely related to the 3. Though. I want to define shortcuts for commands that are not listed there.

e.g. When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, I want

```
\begin{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}
```

to be inserted just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts `\\`.

Comment: You mean new key bindings?

Comment: @JosephWright, what is the difference between `keyboard shortcut` and `keybinding`? Regardless of "terms", I want the `\begin...` stuff to be inserted at cursor position when I press the `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` combination. That's all. Problem is, unlike latex commands like `\begin{equation} \end{equation}`, I cound not find the `\begin{bmatrix}` command itself there. So, I cannot define the shortcut.

Comment: I, sadly, cannot illustrate with screenshot.

Answer (score 51):

In TeXstudio, to create a new code snippet and associate it with a keyboard shortcut, you can create a Macro and then assign a Shortcut to it.

To do this:

**1.** Go to the "`Macros`" menu and choose "`Edit Macros`"

**2.** In the "`Edit Macros`" dialog, click on the "`Add`" button, in the lower left corner of the dialog

**3.** Give the "Macro" a Name, fill the "`Abbreviation`" text field with `$..$` and put your LaTeX code in the "`LaTeX Content" text area with your LaTeX code in this method leave the "Type" radio button with the default value of "Normal"), as illustrated below:

[image: "Edit Macros" dialog]

**EDIT:** As an **alternative method**, in this "Step 3", (Step of the "`Edit Macros`" dialog) - and since the idea is to "create" a new environment (in this case, bmatrix) -  you may choose the "`Environment`" radio button, in the "`Type`" option, instead of the default value of "`Normal`". If you do that, make sure that `%bmatrix` (yes, that percentage sign before `bmatrix` is supposed to be there) is the content in the `"LaTeX Content"`text area (and clear the content of the "Abbreviation" text field). The advantage of this alternative method, as I see it, is that the cursor will be "correctly" placed inside the environment when the Macro is activated. Here's a screenshot for this step with this alternative method:

[image]

**4.** Click in the "OK" button to close the dialog

**5.** Go to the "`Options`" Menu and choose the "`Configure TeXstudio...`" command (first command of the Options Menu)

**6.** In the "`Configure TeXstudio...`" dialog, choose "Shortcuts" in the vertical navigation in the left side, and expand the "Menus" -> "Macros" option in the right hand side, to reveal your Macros, including your newly added "3: My Bmatrix Macro" like shown here:

[image: "Configure TeXstudio" dialog]

**7.** Double click the "`Current Shortcut`" column and press the "Ctrl+Shift+B" key combination. This will change the value of the column to "`Ctrl+Shift+B`"

You'll probably get a warning dialog box saying that the Keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+B" is already assigned to the command "Unnamed Bookmark". Click on the "`Yes`" button to accept the replacement of the Keyboard Shortcut.

**8.** Click on the "`OK`" button on the "`Configure TeXstudio...`" dialog to close it.

That's it! :-) Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+B` in your documents will insert the code for the `bmatrix` environment, from now on.

Comment: Is there any way to save this configuration so I could send it to myself on another computer?

Comment: The macros I define seem to document specific; is there a way to create new macros which holds for every .tex document I edit?

Comment: Is there any way to put the cursor within the `\begin...` and `\end...` environment after I press the shortkey? The default position of the cursor after using the shortcut is at the end of the code, which is not very convenient.

Comment: @XiaodongQi Place `%|` in the line between `\begin...` and `\end...` in the macro script.

Comment: @Troy: You should absolutely add the `%|` tip to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the "trigger" option instead of shortcuts given the macros are so useful for faster typing and if we use shortcuts could be more complex to remember them.

For example, I created a macro to a *definition* environment that is triggered by the specific command. In this way, when I type **::def**, it is replaced by

```
\begin{definition}

\end{definition}
```