# TexStudio User defined keyboard shortcuts (with highlight arguments)

Tags: texstudio, editors, keyboard

I use TexStudio and I want to make a keyboard shortcut that inserts `\textrm{param}` when I press it where `param` is a parameter to be filled in (similar to how `\frac` has the `num` and `den` parameters).

Is it possible to apply the shortcut with selected source code as a parameter?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129271/defining-new-shortcuts-in-texstudio)? (After all I do not think this is a good idea because I tend to define too much shortcuts and forget them immediately.)

Comment: sorta like that but with a parameter

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to *Macros* menu and choose *Edit Macros*

[image]

Click on the *Add* button and insert a new macro, as in the image below (the *Name* you can choose, of course).

[image]

The *Type* should be *Normal* and the *LaTeX Content* should be `\textrm{%|%|}`. Click on *OK* and then you can insert the macro from *Macros* menu or using its shortcut (in my case, <kbd>Shift+F5</kbd>).

The macro will insert `\textrm{}` with the cursor inside the braces `{}`.

**Note 1.** You can select some text (`foo`) first and execute the macro after to obtain `\textrm{foo}`.

**Note 2.** You can change its shortcut using *Options* menu, *Configure TeXstudio*

[image]

and then *Shortcuts*

[image]