# Formula Shortcuts

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, shortcut

I have to type some formulas of this kind very often $$\mathrm{e}^{\beta \varDelta t}$$

Is there a way I can create some shortcut with collection of such formulas that I can easily access per click so that I don't have to copy-paste them all the time? Something like a favorites bar?

I'm using TeXstudio

Comment: Did you take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245649/texstudio-can-i-define-my-own-keyboard-shortcuts-with-highlight-arguments-preff ?.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a new command in your preamble like so:

```
\newcommand{\myFn}{\mathrm{e}^{\beta \varDelta t}}
```

Then you can simply use your short-hand command, in this case `\myFn`, in your document like so: `$$\myFn$$`.

Comment: The OP might find your macro more useful if you took out the display mode math (the `$$`). Then he could use it inside math mode as part of an equation or expression. Also: `$$` is no longer the best way to display math.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the hint. I updated my answer accordingly.