# Insert command with keyboard shortcut in TeXstudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio

For inserting dashed lines inside `matrix` structures, I have to use the command `\hdashline` from the package  *arydshln* prodominantly. I am wondering whether `TeXstudio` supports assigning a specific command or statement to a certain keyboard shortcut.

So more explicitly: 
assign `\hdashline[2pt/2pt]` to the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (any combination will do).

Comment: you can specify it as a macro in `Macro` menu. a tag will call it like you defined it

Comment: Ah, I did look at the macro's, but apparently not good enough. Thanks!

Comment: This ticket answered my question completely: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129271/defining-new-shortcuts-in-texstudio