# Shortcut for adding new frame in beamer using TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

I am new to beamer. There are shortcuts for some of the commands like Ctrl+Shift+I for `\item`. Is there a shortcut for adding new frame in beamer? If no, can I add a new one? I am using TeXStudio.

Comment: This is an editor feature. You haven't told us which editor you are using.

Comment: I am using Texstudio. I have edited my question

Comment: There is already a very comprehensive answer on how to create your own macro in TeXstudio: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129276/117534. Another solution is just to use the existing shortcut `Ctrl+E` which opens a new `\begin{...} ... \end{...}` environment, and you just need to type `frame` in yourself. This is not exactly a complete shortcut, but useful if you can't be bothered to set up a new macro (like me).

Comment: @Troy Thanks.Using the link given in the comment, I could add it.