# Configure the buttons in TeXstudio left panel

Tags: macros, texstudio

I'd like to know if in my `TeX` editor, `TeXstudio`, the buttons can be customized? i.e:

The marked button produces `$  $`, and I'd like to have `${}$`
[image]

This other button produces `\\` and I'd like to have

```
\par
%
```

[image]

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want `${ }$`? (Probably not a good idea.)

Comment: I can't help with the editor, sorry I don't use TeXStudio, but it seems a strange request: you almost never need `\par` in a document and `${}$` similarly is somewhat dangerous to add automatically since `{}` in math mode typically affects spacing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you can edit existing buttons, but you can make new ones, and you can have them insert arbitrary code.

#### Step 1 -- make a macro

Go to Macros --> Edit macros, and make a new macro with the code you want inserted in the "LaTeX content" box:

[image: new texstudio macro]

The `%|` construct is a placeholder only, it indicates where the cursor is placed when you use this macro.

(See Help --> User manual, the section on "Personal macros". See also [Defining New ShortCuts in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129271/defining-new-shortcuts-in-texstudio))

#### Step 2 -- add a new button

Go to Options --> Configure TeXstudio, and look in the Toolbars tab. The toolbar you want to modify is called "Central", so choose that in the first drop-down menu. In the second drop-down menu, choose "All menus". Find the macro you just created, and doubleclick to move it over to the toolbar:

[image: toolbar modification]

- You can choose a different icon by right clicking on the toolbar entry and navigating to an image file. (I don't know where you can find the ones that TeXstudio uses.)
- You can move items up and down by dragging with the mouse

#### Step 3 -- don't use it for what you've said you're going to use it for.

You don't really want to always use `${ .. }$` for inline math, for one thing it inhibits line breaking. And why use `\par`, and not just an empty line?