# Custom Commands for Texstudio Left Panel

Tags: texstudio

I was looking for a way to add custom commands to the Left Panel in Texstudio  (not the toolbar next to the text window) where you can find structure, symbols, etc. as marked in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424986/158760) . I am interested especially in the "Tikz" part because I have a few commands I need sometimes and I can't always remember the right tikz syntax (like `tikzset` and `intersections`). They are too many to add each one to the [toolbar next to the text window](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393725/158760).

I haven't found anything on this topic so far. When I was searching the names in the texstudio path to find the files, in which the entries are stored, I found them in the texstudio.exe (around line 1107400) as some markup language. I am not sure whether you can change text menu entries inside an .exe File, but I am quite sure you shouldn't. Does anyone know a way to add commands in this menu part?

Comment: On the left panel you already have the TI button.

Comment: Yes there is already a Tikz part, but the commands in it aren't very useful for me (i don't neet arrows for example) and i would like to insert my own commands there

Comment: Make a macro, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393725/77895