# TeXStudio and macro/shortcuts

Tags: texstudio, highlighting

In TeXstudio it is possible to use the shortcut `Ctrl + B` to get the following code `\textbf{}` with the cursor in the middle of the parenthesis ready for me to write some text that will be bold.

Question is... I have defined a new command `\hl` to give me highlighted text, but is there a way to provide som shortcut for that or maybe define a macro to get `\hl{}`?

Comment: the question appears to be about texstudio so I removed the texshop and latex3 tags.

Comment: This could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129276/14757